# comparing 3 columns including key value using groupby and count()

Tags: pandas, group-by, count, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset containing three columns. I want to compare them together and find out the count as follows using pandas.

Input:

```
|Key|Name|location|
|---|----|--------|
|112|A   | ABCD   |
|112|A   | ABCD   |
|128|B   | BCDE   |
|138|C   | ABCD   |
|128|B   | BCDE   |
|112|A   | ABCD   |
|115|D   | BCDE   |
```

Desired Output:

```
|location|Name|COUNT     |
|--------|----|----------|     
|ABCD    |A,C |A->1,C-1  |
|BCDE    |B,D |B->1 ,D->1|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @not a robot here. Your desired output is probably not really useful.

Try this:

```
res = df.drop_duplicates().groupby( 'location')['Name'].agg(Count='value_counts').reset_index()
print(res)

  location Name  Count
0     ABCD    A      1
1     ABCD    C      1
2     BCDE    B      1
3     BCDE    D      1
```

Or you do it like this to keep all columns ('key'):

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby('location').value_counts().reset_index(name='Count')

  location  Key Name  Count
0     ABCD  112    A      1
1     ABCD  138    C      1
2     BCDE  128    B      1
3     BCDE  115    D      1
```

If your real data is bigger than this, you can set a `subset` in `drop_duplicates` to define which rows have to be the same to be considered as duplicates. Without it, all columns must be same to be a duplicate.

Comment: I changed the output. The same repeating key needs to be considered as one.Here key 112 repeat 3 times in same loccation abcde. Then the count of A needs to be considered as one.